# Como fazer um Select com vários SUM?

Tags: mysql

Olá, tenho uma tabela de atividades que lista os dados da atividade, inclusive o status dela.

Eu gostaria de somar as atividades de determinado usuário e exibir em um gráfico, mostrando de acordo com o status da atividade. (Tipo, ir somando sempre +1 de acordo com o status).

**Por exemplo:**

O usuário Bruno tem:
25 atividades com status vencida.
10 atividades com status pendente. 
30 atividades com status concluido.

**Estou tentando utilizar o código abaixo, no MySQL:**

```html
SELECT  
  SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'CONCLUIDO' THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS Concluido,
  SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'CONCLUIDO_VENCIDO' THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS Concluido_Vencido,
  SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'INICIADO' THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS Iniciado,
  SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'INICIADO_VENCIDO' THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS Iniciado_Vencido,
  SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'PENDENTE' THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS Pendente,
  SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'VENCIDO' THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS Vencido
FROM tbl_atividades WHERE responsavel = "BRUNO";
```

- O código está dando erro.

**Descrição da tabela tbl_atividades:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

** Segue o erro apresentado **
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado!

Comment: Apesar de você não ter informado qual o erro creio que falta o END em cada um dos CASE. Não está faltando a cláusula GROUP BY?

Comment: Ah, desculpe. Vou editar e mostrar o erro.

Comment: Não seria o caso de usar um count com um group by status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A query esta praticamente certa, porém faltou um detalhe para funcionar corretamente, tente desta forma que certamente funcionará.

```
SELECT  
  SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'CONCLUIDO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Concluido,
  SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'CONCLUIDO_VENCIDO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Concluido_Vencido,
  SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'INICIADO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Iniciado,
  SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'INICIADO_VENCIDO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Iniciado_Vencido,
  SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'PENDENTE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Pendente,
  SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'VENCIDO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Vencido
FROM tbl_atividades WHERE responsavel = "BRUNO";
```

Comment: Pohh@ , cara. Era isso mesmo. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

O que você está tentando fazer é contar o número de atividades por usuário. Imagino que o script a seguir resolva o seu problema:

```
select status, count(*)
from tbl_atividades
where responsavel = 'BRUNO'
group by status;
```

Isso vai mostrar quantas ocorrências de cada status existe para aquele determinado usuário.

Comment: Certo, Felipão. Porém eu gostaria de fazer daquela forma ali mesmo. Com o SUM. Agradeço sua tentativa com o COUNT.